# Runnable does not run inside Callable

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, runnable, callable

In the following code I create a callable which creates a Runnable inside the call()-method. My problem is that run()-method is never reached (code does not get executed). Do you know why and how to fix that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Callable<Object> c = new Callable<Object>() {

        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {

            Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("hi");

                }
            };

            return null;
        }
    };

    try {
        c.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You've forgotten invoke `r.run();`

Comment: Well, you actually dont call run method

Answer (score 0):

```
Callable<Object> c = new Callable<Object>() {

            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {

                Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("hi");

                    }
                };
                r.run();
                return null;
            }
        };
        try {
            c.call();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by including some text that explains how your example is different from the OP's example.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know why...

Already explained by others:  You have written code that creates a `Runnable` instance, but your code does not do anything with the instance after creating it.  Your code does not directly call the `run()` method, nor does your code hand the instance off to any other object that would call the method.

> ...and how to fix that?

That would depend on what you want the code to *do*.  There are simpler ways to write a program that prints "hi" if that's all you want.

It looks as if you are trying to learn something, but you haven't told us what you want to learn.